# Storage definition syntax

Tags: pallet, storage, frame

```
    #[pallet::storage]
    pub(super) type ProofMapping<T: Config> = StorageMap<_, Blake2_128Concat, Vec<u8>, (T::AccountId, T::BlockNumber), ValueQuery >;
```

What does the syntax used to define ProofMapping mean? Is ProofMapping an implementation of the generic trait StorageMap that is then implemented by the Pallet Struct?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't exactly understand your question. Are you asking why `T: Config` is needed?

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi I've just realised all storage types are traits so my question is a bit odd since i thought storage was a struct. I am confused about the syntax used to declare ProofMapping, are we creating a new trait that is implemented by the Pallet Struct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each `#[pallet::storage]`, you define a type `NameOfStorage` which has a trait bound for the kind of storage you are defining (`StorageValue`, `StorageMap`, etc...)

From there, the macro generates a `struct _GeneratedPrefixForStorageNameOfStorage`, and this struct implements the [`StorageInstance`](https://crates.parity.io/frame_support/traits/trait.StorageInstance.html) trait.

```
pub trait StorageInstance {
    const STORAGE_PREFIX: &'static str;

    fn pallet_prefix() -> &'static str;
}
```

The purpose of this struct is just to hold the unique storage prefix for the storage item, and thus only implements those two things above, giving the storage item a unique key in storage.

You can see examples of this struct in the Balances Pallet:

https://crates.parity.io/pallet_balances/pallet/struct._GeneratedPrefixForStorageAccount.html

This Struct is actually the first parameter of the trait:

```
#[pallet::storage]
pub(super) type NameOfStorage<T: Config> = StorageMap<_, Blake2_128Concat, Vec<u8>, (T::AccountId, T::BlockNumber), ValueQuery >;
-----------------------------------------------------^^^
```

But we use macro magic to hide this from the user using type inference syntax. Although it is really macro magic under the hood...

Now that the `StorageMap` trait has this struct and the prefix it needs, the rest of the storage APIs are automatically generated as you would expect on top of the type.

You can really naively think about the storage item as (super simplified, and not accurate):

```
struct Prefix;
impl StorageInstance for Prefix {
    fn prefix() -> Vec<u8> {
        "PalletName".to_bytes() + "StorageName".to_bytes()
    }
}

type MyStorage = StorageValue<Prefix, Type>;

trait StorageValue<Prefix, Type> {
    fn get() -> Option<Type> {
        sp_io::storage::get(Prefix::prefix())
    }

    fn set(value: Type) {
        sp_io::storage::set(Prefix::prefix(), value)
    }

    fn kill() {
        sp_io::storage::clear(Prefix::prefix())
    }
    
    // etc...
}
```

All we have done with the Pallet Storage macros is generate for you a unique prefix using the Pallet Name and Storage Name, and the storage trait itself actually does all the heavy lifting, and implements all the interfaces with the underlying `sp-io` layer.